# Angular/RxJS Issues sorting data

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

In Angularjs you can sort using filters but that is'nt supported in Angular so I'm having difficulties returning sorted data. I read that you should do the sorting in the component code instead of using pipes for better optimisation but I'm failing to add sorting to my component code while using rxjs as its confusing.
It seems i need to map or pipe the observable into a sorting algorithm but implementation is failing.

please help.

media-sorted.component.ts

```
export class MediaSortedComponent implements OnInit {
  apiUrl = 'assets/media.json';
  mediaCollection: Array<Media>;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.imageJson.subscribe((result) => this.mediaCollection = result );
  }

  get imageJson(): Observable<Array<Media>> {
    return this.http.get<Array<Media>>(this.apiUrl);
  }
}
```

assets/media.json

```
[
  {
     "url":"assets/images/dogs/australian-shepherd.jpg",
     "description":"Australian Shepherd",
     "sortOrder": 5
  },
  {
     "url":"assets/images/dogs/beagle.jpg",
     "description":"Beagle",
     "sortOrder": 2
  },
  {
     "url":"assets/images/dogs/corgi.jpg",
     "description":"Corgi",
     "sortOrder": 6
  },
  {
     "url":"assets/images/dogs/dalmatian.jpg",
     "description":"Dalmatian",
     "sortOrder": 3
  },
  {
     "url":"assets/images/dogs/husky.jpg",
     "description":"Husky",
     "sortOrder": 4
  },
  {
    "url":"assets/images/dogs/golden-retriever.jpg",
    "description":"Golden Retriever",
    "sortOrder": 1
 }
]
```

I tried this pipe map sort but then i get the error "Property 'sortOrder' does not exist on type 'Media'.ts(2339)"

```
get imageJson(): Observable<Array<Media>> {
    return this.http.get<Array<Media>>(this.apiUrl).pipe(
      map(results => results.sort((x,y) => x.sortOrder - y.sortOrder))
    );
  }
```

Comment: Try switching the return type from `get<Array<Media>>` for `get<Media[]>`.

Comment: Your sort method looks okay. What does the definition of the `Media` class look like?

Comment: Changing get<Array<Media>> to get<Media[]> worked, thanks!